# Docker Cassandra Access in Client Running Under Same Docker

Tags: cassandra, docker-compose, datastax-java-driver

My docker-compose file as below,

```
cassandra-db:
    container_name: cassandra-db
    image: cassandra:4.0-beta1
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./out/cassandra_data:/var/lib/cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='cassandra-cluster'
      - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=256
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    networks:
      - my-network
client-service:
    container_name: client-service
    image: client-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    ports:
      - 8087:8087
    links:
      - cassandra-db
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
```

I use Datastax Java driver to connect cassandra in client service, which also runs inside docker.

```
CqlSession.builder()
                .addContactEndPoint(new DefaultEndPoint(
                        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("cassandra-db",9042)))
                .withKeyspace(CassandraConstant.KEY_SPACE_NAME.getValue())
                .build()
```

I use DNS name to connect but not connected, i tried with Docker IP of cassandra container, and `depends-on` also.

Any issue with docker-compose file?

Comment: please run `docker network ls` in order to list all declared networks, what is a real name of network declared in your `docker-file.yml`, is it really `my-network` ?

Comment: yes it is, and checked already it is ```bridge``` network.